# Structured Stream-Stream join is not happening in JSON from Kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

Application listening 2 kafka topics

1. userevent
2. paymentevent

Payload for userevent

```
{"userId":"Id_223","firstname":"fname_223","lastname":"lname_223","phonenumber":"P98202384_223","usertimestamp":"Apr 5, 2019 2:58:47 PM"}
```

Payload for paymentevent

```
{"paymentUserId":"Id_227","amount":1227.0,"location":"location_227","paymenttimestamp":"Apr 5, 2019 3:00:03 PM"}
```

Based on userId=paymentuserid , We need to merge the record.

Its seems like application is not able to parse the record from Kafka topic.

There must something on from_json  I am missing.

Can someone provide early feedback?

Here is console output without any join happening. no records.

```
+------+---------+--------+-----------+-------------+-------------+------+--------+----------------+
|userId|firstname|lastname|phonenumber|usertimestamp|paymentuserId|amount|location|paymenttimestamp|
+------+---------+--------+-----------+-------------+-------------+------+--------+----------------+
+------+---------+--------+-----------+-------------+-------------+------+--------+----------------+
```

Here is code.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Stream2StreamJoin  implements CommandLineRunner{



    private static final Logger LOGGER =
              LoggerFactory.getLogger(Stream2StreamJoin.class);

    @Value("${kafka.bootstrap.server}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Value("${kafka.userevent}")
    private String usereventTopic;

    @Value("${kafka.paymentevent}")
    private String paymenteventTopic;

    public void processData() {

        System.out.println(bootstrapServers);
        System.out.println(usereventTopic);
        System.out.println(paymenteventTopic);

        LOGGER.info(bootstrapServers);
        LOGGER.info(usereventTopic);
        LOGGER.info(paymenteventTopic);


        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Stream2StreamJoin").setMaster("local[*]");

        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(10));



        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                  .builder()
                  .appName("Stream2StreamJoin")
                  .getOrCreate();

        spark.sparkContext().setLogLevel("ERROR");

        StructType userSchema =  DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] { 
                DataTypes.createStructField("userId", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("firstname", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("lastname", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("phonenumber", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("usertimestamp", DataTypes.TimestampType, true)
                });


        StructType paymentSchema =  DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] { 
                DataTypes.createStructField("paymentuserId", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("amount", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("location", DataTypes.StringType, true),                
                DataTypes.createStructField("paymenttimestamp", DataTypes.TimestampType, true)
                });



        Dataset<Row> userDataSet=spark.readStream().format("kafka")
                  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers)
                  .option("subscribe", usereventTopic)
                  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
                  .load().selectExpr("CAST(value  AS STRING) as userEvent")
                     .select(functions.from_json(functions.col("userEvent"),userSchema).as("user"))
                     .select("user.*")
                     ; 



        Dataset<Row> paymentDataSet=spark.readStream().format("kafka")
                  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers)
                  .option("subscribe", paymenteventTopic)
                  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
                  .load().selectExpr("CAST( value AS STRING) as paymentEvent")
                     .select(functions.from_json(functions.col("paymentEvent"),paymentSchema).as("payment"))
                     .select("payment.*")
                     ;

        Dataset<Row> userDataSetWithWatermark = userDataSet.withWatermark("usertimestamp", "2 hours");

        Dataset<Row> paymentDataSetWithWatermark = paymentDataSet.withWatermark("paymenttimestamp", "3 hours");

        Dataset<Row> joindataSet =  userDataSetWithWatermark.join(
                paymentDataSetWithWatermark,
                  expr(
                          "userId = paymentuserId AND usertimestamp >= paymenttimestamp AND usertimestamp <= paymenttimestamp + interval 1 hour")
                );

        joindataSet.writeStream().format("console").start();



        try {

            spark.streams().awaitAnyTermination();
        } catch (StreamingQueryException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        processData();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "/Users/workspace/java/spark-kafka-streaming");

        SpringApplication.run(Stream2StreamJoin.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Does it need to be Spark? Maybe KSQL or Kafka Streams would be easier?

Comment: suggestions (build incrementally):
1) did you check whether either datasets produce records (when sent to console stream)? 

2) try without watermarks and verify whether join is producing any data at all

3) now add watermarks and check final result

Comment: KQL and  kafka streaming are not option here since we strongly believe in Open Source Products. Thanks for adding other alternative here for other folks

Comment: We tried to debug application that way only but google gson is really behaving weird while producing message and showing same schema as jackson but kafka is not able to unerstand while consuming.

Comment: Maybe the your date format is not the one TimestampType can understand automatically. You can get it to StringType and see whether the rows are printing, and apply date function to make them convert to TimestampType afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem using jackson library on event producer instead of google gson library.

Consumer side its not able to understand what is json object receiving from topic.

~Keep Learning Keep Growing